# How to fix the django_sites table?

Tags: django, django-admin

Trying to get an `oauth` module to work I made the pro-move of : `manage.py reset sites`

This had the effect killing the admin and login functionality of my site.

So, my question is how to I get back to square one and fix what I broke.

Here is my current error when trying to display the admin tool:

```
DoesNotExist at /admin/
Site matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://mdev.5buckchuck.com/admin/
Django Version: 1.3
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Site matching query does not exist.`
```

I looked at the documentation but I am lost and tired in it:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/sites/

It seemed to indicate: `manage.py syncdb`

So, I wonder what to do next...

Comment: "I made the the pro-move..." Oh man that gave me a good belly laugh. Anyway I somehow got to the same point as you, but in my case by logging out...

Comment: Related issue: search your settings file for `SITE_ID`, this error could indicate that someone just set that to the wrong value. (Like if it's complaining that no site with `pk` > 1 exists, `SITE_ID` is no longer the default value, and may indicate a simple issue like this.) I know this doesn't answer your issue above, but could be relevant to future searchers.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You don't really need the `sites` framework if you only run one site from the project, so the easiest fix would be to remove the following item from your `INSTALLED_APPS` and the error should go away:

```
'django.contrib.sites'
```

You can also re-create the missing `Site` object from shell. Run `python manage.py shell` and then:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
Site.objects.create(pk=1, domain='mdev.5buckchuck.com', name='5buckchuck.com')
```

Comment: Huge thanks man, I am using he django-allauth bundle and its super sensitive to it, so had to go back. Thanks soo much.

Comment: This worked for me but I have no idea why it was needed. Any ideas why site was not created to start with ?

Comment: Hi, am running into the same issue when I do an "sudo rb-site install /var/www/rb.myexample.com". The error is get is:"django.contrib.sites.models.DoesNotExist: Site matching query does not exist". Where is INSTALLED_APPS? I would like to remove the line as you suggested and try again. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Provide SITE_ID=1 in settings.py. This will work.

Comment: Sometimes if you add more Sites via Admin and delete some of them each site has an ID, it was not working for me once I changed the ID in the DB it started working, so make sure SITE_ID matches the ID in the database. That solved for me.

Answer (score 1):

I went through this problem too, while playing with `django-allauth`. The application offers the ability to delete sites. If you delete the one designated by the `SITE_ID` parameter in `settings.py`, you'll have to point the correct PK of another valid site.

If you deleted the default site `example.com`(changes are you did some cleanup after adding another site), you may simply want to select the other site you created by setting SITE_ID to 2 for example. If you work with SQL database, look for the `django_site` table, and locate the site ID you wish to work with.

This way, no need to go into shell and recreating a not necessary desired site.

Answer (score 0):

If you need sites, you can use data fixtures. Read the docs for tip about [enabling the sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework).